# How to config ssh git

Tags: git, github

I've been having a hard time lately setting up and creating a key on ssh, how do I get rid of the problem I'm having

```
git conifg ssh
```

Comment: What's your problem? please, share the error that will show to you.

Comment: If you want to generate SSH key, you should use this command **`ssh-keygen`**  .

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an SSH Key Pair, you need to run the command `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C my-key-name`.

This command will generate two files. The one ending with .pub is the publick key you have to upload to GitHub.

`$ cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Paste the content to the GitHub page under Settings > SSH and GPG keys > Add SSH Key.

Then, you can test it running `$ ssh -T git@github.com`.

If you see a message such as `Hi <your user>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`, it means you can start using Git with the SSH key. :)